# Yapsy throws TypeError on init, missing arguments on init

Tags: python

I've been working with Yapsy (v. 1.10.423) lately, and I've run across an issue with (I think) the package, which is latest from PyPi.

The trace I'm getting is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./clayrd.py", line 256, in <module>
    run()
  File "./clayrd.py", line 202, in run
    loadPlugins()
  File "./clayrd.py", line 121, in loadPlugins
    _pluginMgr.collectPlugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yapsy/PluginManager.py", line 531, in collectPlugins
    self.loadPlugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yapsy/PluginManager.py", line 513, in loadPlugins
    plugin_info.plugin_object = element()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

The method in question that begins that trace is below

```
def loadPlugins():
    """
    Load up all of our plugins
    """

    # Set plugin dir and horde them
    _pluginMgr  =   PluginManager() # Defined at start of script
    _pDir       =   os.path.join(_config['run_dir'], _pluginDir)
    _logger.info("Worker is loading plugins from {}".format(_pDir))
    _pluginMgr.setPluginPlaces([_pDir])
    _pluginMgr.collectPlugins() # This is line 121

    # Attempt plugin activation
    for plugin in _pluginMgr.getAllPlugins():
        _logger.info("Worker attempting to activate plugin {}".format(plugin.name))

        _loaded =   _pluginMgr.activatePluginByName(plugin.name)
        if _loaded == False:
            _logger.warn("Failed to load plugin {}".format(plugin.name))
            continue

        else:
            _logger.info("Plugin {} loaded successfully. Loading dependencies...".format(plugin.name))
```

My question is simply: is this truly a bug with Yapsy, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Hi, I'm yapsy's maintainer and I also saw your message in the bug tracker. I've answered below with the hope it helps, and I don't think it's bug from yapsy (except maybe if we consider the unclear strack as a bug).

Comment: Cheers, Thibauld. Appreciate the response below. As I said below, I spent some time digging through PluginManager.py and was able to sort it out. You are indeed correct that my error above stems from the fact that I was trying to pass in arguments during my instantiation phase, which Yapsy isn't designed to do. Thank you for the response and the verification! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `element` that is being 'called' at the bottom of the stack is actually the plugin class that yapsy is trying to instanciate. So that `element()` actually calls the plugin class's `__init__` method.

Getting back to the exception message, this seems to indicate that your plugin class has a constructor that requires more arguments than just `self` but yapsy expects the plugin class to require no explicit argument at construction time.

As a consequence you should check the definition of the plugin class of the plugin that is being loaded because it's very likely where the problem is.

If the class' init only has one arg `self` then you may have a look at the [trouble shooting documentation for yapsy](http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/Advices.html#plugin-class-detection-caveat) that describes possibly related caveats.

If none of this helped, you can submit a small code sample of a plugin file that causes the problem.

Comment: I was rooting around in the Yapsy code yesterday and I came to essentially the same conclusion that you'd explained above. Yapsy wants no arguments at construction time. Appreciate your response to confirm what I found! :)